# how to get webscript url parameters

Tags: alfresco, alfresco-share, alfresco-webscripts

i have a webscript where i try to get two parameters `filename` and `content` passed on the url when i call this webscript but when i call the webscript whith this url  `http://localhost:8080/alfresco/service/fr/starxpert/workflows-repository/create-save-workflow-files?filename=testFileName="testFileName"&&content="testContent"` i get this error:

```
The Web Script /alfresco/service/fr/starxpert/workflows-repository/create-save-workflow-files has responded with a status of 404 - Not Found.

404 Description:    Requested resource is not available.

Message:    06280086 Script url /fr/starxpert/workflows-repository/create-save-workflow-files does not map to a Web Script.
```

There is my webscript files:

createAndSaveWorkflowFile.get.desc.xml:

```
<webscript> 
  <shortname>Creation and save new workflow file</shortname> 
  <description>create an workflow JSON file and save it into StarXpert Workflow repository</description>
  <url>/fr/starxpert/workflows-repository/create-save-workflow-files/{filename}/{content}</url> 
  <format default="json">extension</format> 
  <authentication>user</authentication> 
  <family>StarXpert</family>
</webscript>
```

createAndSaveWorkflowFile.get.js:

```
var fileName=args.filename;
var properties=args.content;
logger.log(fileName);
model.filename=fileName;
model.properties=properties;
```

createAndSaveWorkflowFile.get.json.ftl:

```
{
    "arguments":[
                    "fileName":"${fileName}",
                    "properties":"${properties}"
                ]   
}
```

Can you tell me what i make wrong, or take me an example to how call the webscript using two arguments on the url, and then get these argument on the webscript.

Comment: Your call should be  http://localhost:8080/alfresco/service/fr/starxpert/workflows-repository/create-save-workflow-files/testFileName/testContent, in accordance with your webscript definition

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have declared that your URL uses path arguments:

```
/fr/starxpert/workflows-repository/create-save-workflow-files/{filename}/{content}
```

But when you are invoking your script you are using query string arguments:

```
/alfresco/service/fr/starxpert/workflows-repository/create-save-workflow-files?filename=testFileName="testFileName"&&content="testContent"
```

Your controller assumes query string arguments, so I will assume that's what you intend.

Further, your URL looks off.

To use query string arguments your URL should be:

```
/alfresco/service/fr/starxpert/workflows-repository/create-save-workflow-files?filename=testFileName&content=testContent
```

If you want your descriptor to match that, you need to change it to:

```
<url>/fr/starxpert/workflows-repository/create-save-workflow-files?filename={filename}&amp;content={content}</url>
```

Notice that the ampersand is escaped so that the XML remains valid.

Comment: Ok, i will try this. Can you tell me if it's the right way to get the arguments from the url, when i use `var fileName=args.filename` in the controller ?

Comment: Yes, tried it and all works fine for me. Thanks @Jeff